# Differential 1-form and system of PDEs

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am working with the following difference of 1-forms
$$d\omega = \alpha - \beta$$
where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $\alpha = ydz$ and $\beta = (y-2y\sin^2(x))dx + (\sin(x)\cos(x))dy + ydz$.

So
\begin{align*}
d\omega &=ydz - [(y-2y\sin^2(x))dx + (\sin(x)\cos(x))dy + ydz] \\
&= (2y\sin^2(x)-y)dx + (-\sin(x)\cos(x))dy +0dz.
\end{align*}

My goal is to determine $\omega$. I have tried to anti-differentiate each term separately so that when the exterior derivative is taken, the result is $d\omega$. However, I was told that I will need to generate three partial differential equations for $\omega$ and then possibly use Maple or MatLab to solve the system of PDEs.

I am not sure how I am to generate these three PDEs from
$$d\omega =  (2y\sin^2(x)-y)dx + (-\sin(x)\cos(x))dy$$
and was hoping someone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d\omega$ is a 1-form, $\omega$ must be a 0-form, or a function.  The total derivative is then given by
\begin{equation}
d\omega = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z}dz,
\end{equation}
so you need to set
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} = 2y\sin^2(x)-y
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} = -\sin(x)\cos(x),
\end{equation}
and also require that $\partial\omega/\partial z=0$, and then solve for $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand properly, $\omega$ is a function and thus $d\omega$ is an exact one-form. Since $d\omega = \alpha - \beta$, 
$$d(d\omega) = 0 = d\alpha - d\beta, \,\, \text{ that is } \,\, d\alpha = d\beta.$$ This is a necessary condition (and in the case of simply connected spaces, as is the case here, it is a sufficient one) that guarantees that if $d\alpha - d\beta = 0$ then there exists a function $\omega$ such that $d\omega = \alpha - \beta$. Thus, before you start, you need to check that $d\alpha = d\beta$. If that's not true, then you cannot find $\omega$. But if it is true, and your forms look like $$\alpha = \alpha_1 dx + \alpha_2 dy + \alpha_3dz$$  $$\beta = \beta_1 dx + \beta_2 dy + \beta_3dz$$
then 
$$\alpha - \beta = (\alpha_1 - \beta_1) dx + (\alpha_2 - \beta_2) dy + (\alpha_3-\beta_3) dz$$
$$d\omega = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z} dz$$ and then 
$d\omega= \alpha-\beta$ can be written component-wise
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} &= \alpha_1 - \beta_1\\
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} &= \alpha_2 - \beta_2\\
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z} &= \alpha_3 - \beta_3\\
\end{align} 
and you need to integrate them. From the first equation
$$\omega(x,y,z) = \int_{x_0}^{x}\Big(\alpha_1(\tilde{x},y,z) - \beta_1(\tilde{x},y,z)\Big)d\tilde{x} + g_1(y,z) = f_1(x,y,z) + g_1(y,z),$$
where $f_1(x,y,z) = \int_{x_0}^{x}\Big(\alpha_1(\tilde{x},y,z) - \beta_1(\tilde{x},y,z)\Big)d\tilde{x}$ and $g_1(y,z)$ is an unknown function only of $y$ and $z$. To find it, plug in the second equation
$$\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} (x,y,z) = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(x,y,z) + \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}(y,z) = \alpha_2(x,y,z) - \beta_2(x,y,z),$$
express the derivative for the unknown function $g_1$:
$$\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}(y,z) = \alpha_2(x,y,z) - \beta_2(x,y,z) - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(x,y,z),$$
the right hand side is guaranteed to be independent of $x$ by the closeness condition $d\alpha-d\beta = 0$. Then integrate with respect to $y$
to obtain and expression for $g_1(y,z)$ of the form $g_1(y,z) = g_2(y,z) + h_1(z)$, where $g_2(y,z)$ is a known function obtain by integration of the right hand side of the equation above and thus $\omega(x,y,z) = f_1(x,y,z) + g_2(y,z) + h_1(z)$ is plugged in the last equation of 
$$\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial z}(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}(x,y,z) + \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial z}(y,z) + \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}(z)= \alpha_3(x,y,z) - \beta_3(x,y,z)$$ and obtain an expression for the derivative of $h_1$
$$\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}(z) = \alpha_3(x,y,z)  - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}(x,y,z) - \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial z}(y,z) - \beta_3(x,y,z)$$ which is again guaranteed to depend only on $z$, so integrate it and obtain the last function $h_1(z)$. Thus
$\omega(x,y,z) = f_1(x,y,z) + g_2(y,z) + h_1(z)$